# How do i get source code for Jboss AS 7.1.1 from GIT?

Tags: git, jboss, jboss7.x

I know how to get the latest source from GIT which is version 7.1.2 but i want a previous version (7.1.1.final), where can i find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/jbossas/jboss-as/tags

Answer (score 0):

Once you have cloned the repo, type: `git checkout 7.1.0.Final`